# Steps to simplify specific fraction

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

What are the steps to simplify the first fraction to the second?

$$\frac{\frac{3-(3+h)}{3(3 + h)}} {h} \implies \frac{-1}{3(3 + h)}$$

I assume the first step would be to re-write it like so:

$$\frac{3-(3+h)}{3(3 + h)h}$$

But after that I don't know where to go...

Comment: $3-(3+h)=-h$ on the numerator (top line) and cancel the $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the following steps $$\frac{3-(3+h)}{3(3+h)h}$$$$=\frac{3-3-h}{3(3+h)h}$$$$=\frac{-h}{3(3+h)h}$$Cancelling $h$ in numerator & denominator  $$=\frac{-1}{3(3+h)}$$